# How to show the activity indicator on tap gesture

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show the activity indicator on tap gesture and also navigate from current viewcontroller to next viewcontroller I have written code on tap gesture method my code is -

```
- (void)tapToAutoFocus:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    textLabel.hidden = YES;
    indicator  = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 150, 30, 30)];
    [indicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator startAnimating];

    AccountAnfordernViewController *accountAnfordernViewController = [[AccountAnfordernViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:accountAnfordernViewController animated:YES];
    [accountAnfordernViewController release];
}
```

It navigates to next view controller but indicator are not showing, I want when it navigate to nextviewcontroller at that time indicator also should be show for some time and then navigate to next view controller. What should I do for that?

Comment: Why do you want to show the activity indicator? Does it take time to create the next view controller?

Comment: actually i want to show the loading(like indicator) when navigate it ges to server at that time i want to show indicator.

Comment: When do you access the server? Is it in the code you posted?

Comment: yeah when we tap the image will go to server and next viewcontroller wants to be open.

Comment: Does the server access happen before or after the new controller? I still don't quite understand.

Comment: after server access then new controller.

Comment: @jtbandes let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2725/discussion-between-pinku-and-jtbandes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need to do something like this:

```
- (void)tapToAutoFocus:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    textLabel.hidden = YES;
    indicator  = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 150, 30, 30)];
    [indicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [self.view addSubview:indicator];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(pushAccountAnfordern) withObject:nil afterDelay: 0.1];
}

- (void) pushAccountAnfordern;
{
    AccountAnfordernViewController *accountAnfordernViewController = [[AccountAnfordernViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:accountAnfordernViewController animated:YES];
    [accountAnfordernViewController release];
}
```

You can vary the delay. And, indeed, 0.0 may be just fine. This way of doing it lets the current run loop end, giving a chance for the spinner to start showing before starting the next bit of code. For a different approach (with potential side effects) to forcing the spinner to start before the current run loop ends this this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041261/how-to-display-uiactivityindicatorview-before-rotation-begins).