# UIActivityIndicatorView in UITableViewCell does not stop spinning

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a subclassed UITableViewCell named AccountView which contains an UIActivityIndicatorView. Each cell is supposed to contain a Twitter account. When the user posts a message to Twitter, the UIActivityIndicatorView is supposed to start spinning, then stop animating when the twitter request handler is executed:

```
[postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error){
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"TWITTER ERROR: %@",error);
        }
        NSLog(@"Posted successfully");
        AccountCell *cell = (AccountCell *)[accountTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[accounts indexOfObject:account] inSection:0]];
        NSLog(@"Cell isSpinning?  :%d",[[cell activity] isAnimating]);
        [[cell activity] stopAnimating];
        NSLog(@"Cell isSpinning?  :%d",[[cell activity] isAnimating]);
    }];
```

This all works fine when posting a short message to Twitter, however, when the TWRequest contains an image to be uploaded, after a few seconds, the post with image appears on Twitter, and I see the following message in the console:

```
2011-12-10 00:13:22.085 TwitTest[14954:1a03] Posted Successfully
2011-12-10 00:13:22.086 TwitTest[14954:1a03] Cell isSpinning?  :1
2011-12-10 00:13:22.088 TwitTest[14954:1a03] Cell isSpinning?  :0
```

But the UIActivityIndicatorView keeps spinning indefinitely (or at least a delay of several seconds), even though the Log messages indicate otherwise. The fact that this only breaks with image upload leads me to believe that maybe I should send the request on a background thread, but I have never dealt with threads before, and couldn't say for sure if that is the problem.

One last thing, if I navigate to different view and return, the UIActivityIndicatorView appears frozen - if I navigate away and return a second time, then it disappears for good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Apple Developer's documentation: "This handler is not guaranteed to be called on any particular thread." Perhaps your interface loop is working and modifications are taken in account after each run loop.

Try to execute interface changes in main thread. Use performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:

Comment: Tried this and it works now. One thing I don't understand though is that the `NSLog` messages that report if the ActivityView is spinning just before and after stopping the spinner both return 1 now.

Comment: Easy, that is because as I supposed, the main thread is working and so that job is not attended immediately. You can force to wait fot that done with performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:YES

Comment: So do you think it's possible that the Twitter framework is pushing all of the requesting onto a background thread, so the `stopAnimating` command is stuck in low priority and not getting executed? I guess I'm confused because the `NSLog` are getting executed, they say the ActivityView shouldn't be spinning, yet it still spins for quite a while.

Comment: There is something you are loosing in that. NSLog and any modification your code do on the UI objects are done just on time. You modify the Activity View setting isAnimating to YES and you write something with NSLog. But then you only have made objects modifications. Then, each time the main loop of your app ends after attending a message, then and only then, the system takes account of the modifications you have done with UI objects and so you can see the results.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the line:

```
[CATransaction flush];
```

after you've sent the stopAnimating message. This will help if the issue is that the event loop isn't coming around quickly enough. Not clear that this is the issue from what you provide, but worth a try.  See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041261/how-to-display-uiactivityindicatorview-before-rotation-begins) for background.

**Updated** you'll need to add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the header file and make sure you've added the QuartzCore framework using the Build Phases (Link Binary With Libraries) option in Targets.

Comment: I added that line in, but got a complier error - looks like I'd have to add in the QuartzCore framework to use this.

Comment: While the solution I marked as correct worked for my above problem, I ran into another where a custom animation was delayed. Your solution did the trick. +1