# UIBarButtonItem resets when switching orientation

Tags: ios, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem, uiactivityindicatorview

When I go from portrait to landscape orientation my uibarbuttonitem resets to what the button is in the storyboard.  On the storyboard I have it set as a refresh button, but during my code execution I set it to an activity indicator.  How do I retain the activity indicator when I switch my orientation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a flag which sets to TRUE only when the code execution is over. On Orientation Change check if this flag is TRUE and set the image accordingly. For further help, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7041261/how-to-display-uiactivityindicatorview-before-rotation-begins)

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try it out!